# Deploy servidor de GraphQL

Tags: nodejs, express, graphql

Hola tengo un servidor de GraphQL, implementado con expressjs, utilizando babel tambien, el detalle es que es mi primer deploy de este tipo, tengo entendido que tengo que quitar nodemon del script que arranca el servidor, ya que es una dependencia de desarrollo, mi pregunta es, como deberia quedar mi package.json para correr correctamente en un entorno de produccion? ya que tambien estoy utilizando babel, Gracias de antemano!.

```js
{
  "name": "graphql-servidor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "servidor",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js"  //script de arranque
  },
  "author": "Victor Bravo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.7.0-alpha.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.8.0",
    "graphql": "^14.4.1",
    "graphql-import": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.5",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

RAIZ DEL PROYECTO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CONTENIDO DE CARPETA DATA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar a producción lo primero que tendrías que hacer es compilar el código utilizando la `cli` de babel. Por ejemplo, si tuvieras todo tu código de NodeJS escrito dentro de la carpeta `src` podrías hacer:

```sh
npx babel src --out-dir lib
```

> [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) es un paquete de `npm` que simplifica ejecutar módulos de `node`. Tiene la ventaja de que intenta correr primero el modulo desde la carpeta `node_modules` local, antes de buscar en el ambiente global, o descargarlo de `npm`. En tu caso es importante porque estas usando la versión `6.26` de Babel, que al día de hoy esta en la `7.5`

Una vez compilado, podrás correr tu aplicación desde la carpeta `lib`. Suponiendo que tu archivo de entrada es `index.js`, podes correr tu aplicación con `node`:

```sh
node ./lib/index.js
```

Si necesitas que la aplicación quede funcionando como un servicio, tenes varias opciones, las cuales varían dependiendo del servidor que tengas. Existen dos módulos populares para gestionar procesos de `node`: [`PM2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), y [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). Te recomiendo que analices ambos para ver cual seria le mejor alternativa.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Una disculpa @guzmonne, me desconecte un poco, te comento el código y la forma en la que están las carpetas distribuidas es la siguiente, no entiendo donde debo ejecutar el comando npx de babel cli, adjunte la foto arriba, hare un deploy en un droplet linux, en DigitalOcean

Comment: Lo tendrías que correr desde la raíz de tu proyecto, y configurar la carpeta donde está la fuente de tu proyecto. En este caso: `data`. Proba con este comando desde la raíz: `npx babel data --out-dir lib`. El resultado será una nueva carpeta llamada `lib` con el código compilado. Lee la documentación de `Babel` para más información.